# Why didn't this format correctly in a comment?

Tags: support, comments, markdown

I commented on a person's question with the following markup:

> ...you have a single-bit mask that increments using  `i <<= 1`, e.g. `for(i = 1; i < 1 << 16; i <<= 1)`...

but the way it appeared was

...you have a single-bit mask that increments using i <<= 1`, e.g.`for (i = 1; i < 1 << 16; i <<= 1)`...

It was as if the first ` were ignored.  The same text in an answer appears correctly. I tried several tweaks to the comment in the 5 minutes I had to edit it, but I eventually gave up.  What could I have done to make it format properly?

Comment: ...you have a single-bit mask that increments using `i <<= 1`, e.g. `for(i = 1; i < 1 << 16; i <<= 1)`...

Comment: Hmm it works here, but not in the code review forum itself.

Comment: Could it have been a typo? Got a link to the comment in question?

Comment: I figured it out -- there was a space after the `.

Comment: @Mat'sMug, I checked the documentation page -- I didn't see anything about a space following a backtick cancelling the formatting.

Comment: You can still iterate, but instead of an index that increments using `i++` you have a single - bit mask that increments using ` i <<= 1`, e.g. `for(i = 1; i < 1 << 16; i <<= 1)`However, with a little imagination, you could find ways to copy whole chunks of a chromosome using `&` with a mask containing all the bits you want to copy set to 1, then using shift operators to align them the way you want and splice them in using the `|` operator.

Answer (score 2):

This is a Stack Exchange wide issue. See this post and its duplicates:

[Could Markdown and mini-Markdown have the same support for backticks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213182/could-markdown-and-mini-markdown-have-the-same-support-for-backticks)

In short, the markdown in posts and the markdown in comments (dubbed "mini-markdown") are implemented differently, and users stumble into all kinds of quirky behavior with the latter. The best we can do is upvote the posts about it on MSE.